# create php array based on another array.

Tags: php, arrays

I want to sort all php arrays based on first main array.

This is the main array which I want to use to sort all other arrays:

```
Array (

[0] => 10
[1] => 14
[2] => 15
[3] => 20
[4] => 21
[5] => 24
[6] => 25
[7] => 28
[8] => 30
[9] => 45
[10] => 60
[11] => 90
[12] => 120
[13] => 150
[14] => 180
[15] => 210
[16] => 240
[17] => 270
[18] => 365

)
```

This are arrays which need to be sorted :

```
Array (

[0] => Array
    (
        [14] => 49.21
        [20] => 71.04
        [25] => 89.58
        [30] => 100.00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [180] => 412.00
        [150] => 347.00
        [120] => 285.00
        [90] => 224.00
        [60] => 165.00
        [30] => 100.00
        [14] => 47.00
    )
```

)

I need that final result look like this:

```
Array (

[0] => Array
    (
        [10] => n/a
        [14] => 49.21
        [15] => n/a
        [20] => 71.04
        [21] => n/a
        [24] => n/a
        [25] => 89.58
        [28] => n/a
        [30] => 100.00
        [45] => n/a
        [60] => n/a
        [90] => n/a
        [120] => n/a
        [150] => n/a
        [180] => n/a
        [210] => n/a
        [240] => n/a
        [270] => n/a
        [365] => n/a
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [10] => n/a
        [14] => 71.04
        [15] => n/a
        [20] => n/a
        [21] => n/a
        [24] => n/a
        [25] => n/a
        [28] => n/a
        [30] => 100.00
        [45] => n/a
        [60] => 165.00
        [90] => 224.00
        [120] => 285.00
        [150] => 347.00
        [180] => 412.00
        [210] => n/a
        [240] => n/a
        [270] => n/a
        [365] => n/a
    )

    )
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does not exactly look like sorting to me. Can you explain what you want to do? To me it looks like filling the array with unused keys and then sorting by this keys (which could be done by `ksort`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it right from your question, you want to make both arrays of the same length and set keys not in them to `"n/a"`.

Variant with `array_merge` ([Demo](http://codepad.org/xiB6VWQv)):

```
$shorten = array(
  0 => 10,
  1 => 14,
  2 => 15,
  3 => 20,
  4 => 21,
  5 => 24,
  6 => 25,
  7 => 28,
  8 => 30,
  9 => 45,
  10 => 60,
  11 => 90,
  12 => 120,
  13 => 150,
  14 => 180,
  15 => 210,
  16 => 240,
  17 => 270,
  18 => 365,
);

$data = array(
  0 => array(
    14 => '49.21',
    20 => '71.04',
    25 => '89.58',
    30 => '100.00',
  ),
  1 => array(
    180 => '412.00',
    150 => '347.00',
    120 => '285.00',
    90 => '224.00',
    60 => '165.00',
    30 => '100.00',
    14 => '47.00',
  ),
);

// default array as the base
$shorten = array_combine($shorten, array_fill(0, count($shorten), 'n/a'));

foreach($data as &$array) {
    // merge to get set members
    $array = array_merge($shorten, $array);
}
unset($array);

var_dump($data);
```

Result:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(23) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [3]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [4]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [5]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [6]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [7]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [8]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [9]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [10]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [11]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [12]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [13]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [14]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [15]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [16]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [17]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [18]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [19]=>
    string(5) "49.21"
    [20]=>
    string(5) "71.04"
    [21]=>
    string(5) "89.58"
    [22]=>
    string(6) "100.00"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(26) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [3]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [4]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [5]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [6]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [7]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [8]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [9]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [10]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [11]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [12]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [13]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [14]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [15]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [16]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [17]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [18]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [19]=>
    string(6) "412.00"
    [20]=>
    string(6) "347.00"
    [21]=>
    string(6) "285.00"
    [22]=>
    string(6) "224.00"
    [23]=>
    string(6) "165.00"
    [24]=>
    string(6) "100.00"
    [25]=>
    string(5) "47.00"
  }
}
```

---

Variant with mapping function ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/hbAGhk)):

```
$shorten = array(
  0 => 10,
  1 => 14,
  2 => 15,
  3 => 20,
  4 => 21,
  5 => 24,
  6 => 25,
  7 => 28,
  8 => 30,
  9 => 45,
  10 => 60,
  11 => 90,
  12 => 120,
  13 => 150,
  14 => 180,
  15 => 210,
  16 => 240,
  17 => 270,
  18 => 365,
);

// overload $shorten array with a mapping function
$shorten = function(array $a) use ($shorten)
{
    $r = array();
    foreach($shorten as $i => $k)
    {
        $r[$k] = isset($a[$k]) ? $a[$k] : 'n/a';
    }
    return $r;
};


$data = array(
  0 => array(
    14 => '49.21',
    20 => '71.04',
    25 => '89.58',
    30 => '100.00',
  ),
  1 => array(
    180 => '412.00',
    150 => '347.00',
    120 => '285.00',
    90 => '224.00',
    60 => '165.00',
    30 => '100.00',
    14 => '47.00',
  ),
);

// apply mapping function to $data
$data = array_map($shorten, $data);

var_dump($data); # result
```

Result:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(19) {
    [10]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [14]=>
    string(5) "49.21"
    [15]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [20]=>
    string(5) "71.04"
    [21]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [24]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [25]=>
    string(5) "89.58"
    [28]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [30]=>
    string(6) "100.00"
    [45]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [60]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [90]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [120]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [150]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [180]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [210]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [240]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [270]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [365]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(19) {
    [10]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [14]=>
    string(5) "47.00"
    [15]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [20]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [21]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [24]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [25]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [28]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [30]=>
    string(6) "100.00"
    [45]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [60]=>
    string(6) "165.00"
    [90]=>
    string(6) "224.00"
    [120]=>
    string(6) "285.00"
    [150]=>
    string(6) "347.00"
    [180]=>
    string(6) "412.00"
    [210]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [240]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [270]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
    [365]=>
    string(3) "n/a"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your initial array is $source, and $todo is your second array with the two subsets, then:

```
$keys = array_flip($todo);
$keys = array_map(function() { return 'n/a'; }, $keys); // set all values to be "n/a";

foreach($todo as $idx => $do) {
   $todo[$idx] = $do + $keys; // merge without renumbering.
}
```

Comment: I thought about array union as well, but the key-order of `$todo` is not preserved, it's added behind. Must not be an issue anyway.

Comment: true enough, but easy enough to ksort() it afterwards if it becomes an issue.